# Who is credited with the creation/invention of the cup product?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, ho.history-overview

Who is credited with the creation/invention of the cup product?  Wikipedia gives credit to several but I wasn't able to confirm.

Comment: Would be better suited at [History of Science and Mathematics SE](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: This is described in Dieudonné's magisterial "A History of Algebraic and Differential Topology, 1900 - 1960". See chapter 4, pages 81--85. The answer is a bit complicated because the notion was first introduced in simplicial cohomology and then later in singular cohomology (after the latter was invented, of course!).

Comment: Thank you Prof. Ruberman!   @Wojowu, I'll be sure to post questions like this in the correct forum. Thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 10):

W. S. Massey gives a rather detailed account in his essay, "A history of cohomology theory" (in *History of Topology*, edited by I. M. James, North Holland, 2006).  The initial idea was due to Alexander and Kolmogoroff, apparently simultaneously and independently, but there were some "bugs" in the original version.  Čech and Whitney, in separate papers, cleaned up the definition (Čech for finite simplicial complexes, Whitney more generally for finite cell complexes).

Comment: Addendum: According to the account in Keith Kendig's book *Never a Dull Moment*, Čech and Whitney did not work entirely independently, although Kendig does not explain in detail the extent of their collaboration, nor why they chose to write two separate papers.